# Is it possible to have multiple send and receive ports for Dart Isolates?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

Is it possible to open a multiple send and receive ports for the same Isolate in Dart?

E.g. Following code sample would have created two isolates with each having its own send port. However, I was wondering if there is any way to create more than one send/receive ports for the same isolate and choose the receive port to send the message to.

```
    #import('dart:isolate');

    echo() {

    }

    main() {
        var sendPort1 = spawnFunction(echo);
        var sendPort2 = spawnFunction(echo);
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify where the two SendPorts from the same isolate would be used? Could you not simply pass the `sendPort` to whatever class or function needs to communicate to the isolate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not sure about multiple receive ports. You can create multiple send ports per receive port. This functionality is build into the ReceivePort class: [ReceivePort.toSendPort](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_isolate/ReceivePort.html#toSendPort)

As indicated at the bottom of the help:

> It is legal to create several SendPorts from the same ReceivePort.

Hope this helps.

Comment: According to documentation, since 2013: *ReceivePort.toSendPort() has been changed to the getter ReceivePort.sendPort*. See: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/g/announce/c/EVUMkZXFXtY

Answer (score 4):

You can actually create any number of ReceivePorts, and then as Matt said, any number of SendPorts per ReceivePort.

By default an isolate, including the main isolate, has a ReceivePort created and available through the `port` getter. This ReceivePort is connected to the SendPort returned from `spawnFunction()` and `spawnUri()`. But you can create a new ReceivePort with `new ReceivePort()`, then you can create as many connected SendPorts as you want via `toSendPort()`. To use them you send the new SendPort itself along with a message on the original SendPort you either got from `spawnFunction()`, or via `ReceivePort.receive()`.

By doing this you can set up multiple "channels" between two isolates. I haven't played with it yet to see how this works in practice yet, I've been multiplexing channels via structured messages on one SendPort.

Note that you can create a ReceivePort in any isolate: the parent isolate or the child isolate. So if you want the partent to have two SendPorts to the child, then you need one from `spawnFunction()` and another that's passed from the child back to the parent in a message.

Here's your example changed to use multiple SendPorts. The steps:

1. main: Spawn an isolate
2. main: Send a message with a SendPort so that the isolate can send a message back
3. echo: Create a second ReceivePort in the isolate
4. echo: Receive a message in the isolate with a replyTo SendPort
5. echo: Create a SendPort from the ReceivePort and send it back
6. main: Receive the message and SendPort from echo

Now main() has two independent SendPorts to the isolate.

```
#import('dart:isolate');

echo() {
  var port2 = new ReceivePort(); // 3

  port2.receive((m, p) {
    print("two: $m");
  });

  port.receive((m, p) { // 4
    print("one: $m");
    p.send("ack", port2.toSendPort()); // 5
  });
}

main() {
  port.receive((m, sendPort2) { // 6
    sendPort2.send("hello 2");
  });
  var sendPort1 = spawnFunction(echo); // 1
  sendPort1.send("hello 1", port.toSendPort()); // 2
}
```

This prints:

```
one: hello 1
two: hello 2
```

Whew!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Justin is basically right, but caused me some trouble because the isolate stopped responding after step 5 has been executed. So here is an updated version that actually worked in my context:

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';

echo() {
  var port2 = new ReceivePort();

  port2.receive((m, p) {
    print("two: $m");
  });

  port.receive((m, p) {
    print("one: $m");
    p.send(port2.toSendPort());
  });
}

main() {
  var sendPort1 = spawnFunction(echo);
  sendPort1.call("hello 1").then((newPort)=>newPort.send("hello 2"));
}
```

The major difference is simply that the port is send as message rather than using the replyTo field. This also allows for a more compact code as the other receiving Port is not required.